# How use dynamic scheduler in spring framework?

Tags: spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I'm using Spring Security 4.2. I want to block user for 15 minutes after 3 login failure. For blocking user, change user `status` to `BLOCK`. I want to return it to `ACTIVE` after 15 minutes.

I need a dynamic task scheduler that run after 15 minutes and change user `status`.

**Important:** I don't want to run method every 15 minutes, I want to run method after 15 minutes *if needed*.

**How do I implement it?**

Answer (score 1):

I have some approach. I guess that you should use `User` class like following:

```
class User {
    // ...
    private Status status;
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;
    // ...
}
```

So that, you should update `status` and `lastUpdated` fields during a user blocking.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void block(User user) {
        user.setStatus(Status.BLOCKED);
        user.setLastUpdated(LocalDateTime.now());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

After that you can use Spring Scheduler which run every minute and finds users that were blocked 15 minutes ago and sets `status` to `ACTIVE`.

```
@Component
public class UserActivator {

    private boolean activateUsers = false;

    @Scheduled("0 * * * * *")
    public void activateUsers() {
        if (activateUsers) {
            // find users that were deactivated 15 minutes ago and change status to active
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add `@EnableScheduling` to your Spring config.

Comment: I have same problem for ip blocking. This method has too much overhead.

Comment: okay, you can use native query to update status for blocked users. So that you shouldn't get users before and it will be more efficient.

Comment: also if you have the sam problem for ip blocking, you can create separate method. Spring allows to configure thread pool for schedulers and you can do that without losing performance.

Comment: I don't want to update user `status` every `USER_STATUS_JOB` time, but I want to update it if needed.

Comment: But you will update only users who was blocked 15 minutes ago

Comment: Yes, I want to call method if needed. If there are no user blocked, method don't call.

Comment: I updated my answer. I added some flag which shows if there are users to be activated. I think in this case you should think about how to handle this flag in case of multithreading

Answer (score 0):

You might have table defination for doing this. But this is how I do it generally.

Create a seprate table to maintain the failure count.

Then on basis of  this you can check in your service / controller layer.

```
    @Controller
    public Class LoginController{

        @Autowired
        private UserLoginFailureRepository userLoginFailureRepository;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepostory userRepository;

        @Transactional
        public void login(){

        UserLoginFailure loginFailure = userLoginFailureRepository.getUserLoginfailureDetails(username);
        if (loginFailure != null) {
        loginFailure.setFailureCount(1l + loginFailure.getFailureCount());

        if (loginFailure.getFailureCount() > loginFailureCount) {
        // block the user.
        User user = userRepository.getUser(username);
        user.setStatus(BLOCK);
        user.setModificationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Create a seprate Scheduled Job to check and update User Status and reset UserLoginFailure count.

```
    @Component
    public class userPasswordResetJob{

        @Autowired
        private UserLoginFailureRepository userLoginFailureRepository;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepostory userRepository;

        @Scheduled(cron = "${USER_STATUS_JOB}")
        public void loginDay() throws Exception{
            // Have your logic to update the User status and reset the failure count.

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to update user `status` every `USER_STATUS_JOB` time, but I want to update it if needed.

Comment: Just Check the modficationDate was 15 Minutes before the current time and then only update it..so It wont update on every User_Status_Job time.

Comment: Or other option is to Create DB sql event that will do the update if required.